# DBLookUpComboBox не раскрывается полностью

Tags: delphi

Добрый день, товарищи!

На форме размещен DBLookUpComboBox. Настроен вроде бы нормально, данные отображает корректно. Но при раскрытии списка появляется только одна строка.

[image]

Если начинаю стрелочками прокручивать список вниз, то при раскрытии появляется больше строк.

[image]

Изначально установлено **DBLookupComboBox.DropDownRows:= 7;**
Что нужно сделать, чтобы список при раскрытии сразу показывал указанное количество строк?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделал костыль и заработало, как надо:

при открытии формы для всех лукапов **DBLookupComboBox.ListSource.DataSet.Last**;

Answer (score -1):

Решение:

```
dataset (TMemTableEh) - FeatchAll - True
```